# How to restore the app states and window by re-clicking the icon?

Tags: android

If my app is minimized to the background, I found it reopened rather than restoring the window and its states after I clicked the app icon. How can I restore it?

Comment: override 'onNewIntent' 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)

Comment: you need to understand activity life cycle 1st and then use onSavedInstanceState to save desired state and then restore it on opening it again. This link will help you
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work like this: 
in the manifest.xml activity section added `android:launchMode="singleTask"`,  then override the onNewIntent method:

```
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        setIntent(intent);
    }
```